# Deleting current document from firestore database

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database, and a website where you can see the database data and add data to it. The problem is that I don't know how to trigger the current row document name to delete it.

This is how the table looks (at its end I have that little trashcan, and when you press it I want it to delete this row from the database)

[image]

And this is the JavaScript code that displays the data from the database:

```
db.collection("flights").get().then((snapshot) =>{ 
   snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
   let data = doc.data()
   

   //*Calculating block time
   var blocktimeHour = data.landing.slice(0,2) - data.takeoff.slice(0, 2);
   var blocktimeMinute = data.landing.slice(3, 5) - data.takeoff.slice(3, 5);
   //*Setting the blocktime format to HH:MM
   if(blocktimeHour < 10){
      blocktimeHour = `0${blocktimeHour}`
   }

   if(blocktimeMinute < 10){
      blocktimeMinute = `0${blocktimeMinute}`
   }

//*Identifying the current document

    //*Displaying the data on the page
   const list = document.querySelector("#gridcontainer");
   const row = document.createElement("tr");

   row.innerHTML +=  `
   <td class="grid-item">${(data.date)}</td>
   <td class="grid-item">${(data.pilot)}</td>
   <td class="grid-item">${(data.copilot)}</td>
   <td class="grid-item">${(data.takeoff)}</td>
   <td class="grid-item">${(data.landing)}</td>
   <td class="grid-item">${blocktimeHour}:${blocktimeMinute}</td>
   <td class="grid-item">${(data.type)}</td>
   <td class="grid-item">${(data.comment)}</td>
   <td class="grid-item"><button onclick="deleteFlight();"><img src="/Images/deleteButton.svg" ><img></button></td>

   `;

   list.appendChild(row);
   

      
   });
})
```

With that button I want to trigger a function, and I want to pass the current row document name parameter to it, so I can specify which document to delete.

This is the delete function:

```
   function deleteFlight(){
   firebase.firestore()
  .collection("flights")
  .doc(thisDoc)
  .delete()
  .then(() => console.log("Document deleted")) // Document deleted
  .catch((error) => console.error("Error deleting document", error));
}
```

I tried many things, but I have no idea how should I do it

Comment: Inside your function deleteFlight how are you defining `thisDoc`? Seems to me you need to use some query selector to target the row that was clicked possibly using the event from the onClick handler and then using that data to compute a reference to `thisDoc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop that generates the HTML for each document, you'll need to add `doc.id` to the HTML in addition to the relevant fields from `doc.data()`.

```
db.collection("flights").get().then((snapshot) =>{ 
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    let id = doc.id;
    let data = doc.data()
    ...
   <td class="grid-item"><button onclick="deleteFlight('${id}');"><img src="/Images/deleteButton.svg" ><img></button></td>
  })
});
```

You can then use the ID in your `deleteFlight` function to find the correct document, and delete it:

```
function deleteFlight(id){
   firebase.firestore()
  .collection("flights")
  .doc(id)
  .delete()
  .then(() => console.log("Document deleted")) // Document deleted
  .catch((error) => console.error("Error deleting document", error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following documentation:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection.

You can call `.where()` to find documents that match a data field in your database then use `var docRef = db.collection("flights").doc(<result>.id);` to get a reference to a specific document through the document id.
Finally you can call `docRef.delete()`.